# Nhibernate: Batching and StatelessSession

Tags: nhibernate, batch-file, stateless

I was trying around with just setting the batch value in the config file, and I see that there's a visible benefit in using it, as in inserting 25000 entries takes less time then without batching. My question is, what are the counter indication, or the dangers of using batching? As I see it I only see benefits in setting a batch value, and activating it.

Another question is regarding StatelessSession. I was also testing this and I've noticed that when I do a scope.Insert it takes more time compared to doing scope.Save of a regular Session, but when I do a commit it's lightning fast. Is there any reason for a Insert from a StatelessSession to take more time then a Save from a regular Session?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I can only speak to the first issue. A possible negative of having a large batch size is the size of the sql being sent across the wire in one go.